# YTParamAPI page returned the entire HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

```
$http({
        url: 'http://myURL.com/api/',
        method: "POST",
        data: { 'YTParam' : 'test' }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        }, 
        function(response) { // optional
            // failed
        }
    );
```

In my console I see the entire html got printed out, I was expecting the value of `$_POST[myParam]`. Why is that happening?

my PHP as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body{
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<?php

echo $_POST["YTParam"];

if($_POST["YTParam"])
  {
     $YTParam = $_POST["YTParam"];
     echo $YTParam;
  }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I did close every tag properly but have no idea why I have this problem.

Comment: You can use curl or chrome developer tools network panel to view what is actually returned from the server.

Comment: Without the code of http://myURL.com/api, we cannot tell you

Comment: @Mawg thanks for reminding, I've updated my code.

Comment: @OlliM the entire html code..

Comment: So what are you wondering about, that the response contains `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <style type="text/css"> …`? Well that’s because your PHP script _outputs_ that … d’oh!

Comment: Put die after echo variable. Also write your Php code above  whole HTML code if you don't need then remove it

Answer (score 4):

Remove all the html on your .php file, as its role is not to be printed directly in a browser, but to treat data server-side.

So, the remaining part would be :

```
<?php

echo $_POST["YTParam"]; // Will be returned to your JS 

if($_POST["YTParam"])
  {
     $YTParam = $_POST["YTParam"]; 
     echo $YTParam; // Will be returned to your JS
  }

?>
```

Everything you'll `echo` will be returned in `response`, in your JS ajax call.

---

#### Edit

Your data is not in the `$_POST` array, because your angular JS contentType is set to `application/json` by default, and PHP expects `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for a POST request. [Quoting from docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) :

> $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post: (header defaults for POST requests)
>
> Content-Type: application/json

To change this, either change this value in your config :

```
yourApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";  
}]);
```

Or at the time you send your request :

```
$http({
    url: 'http://myURL.com/api/',
    method: "POST",

    headers: {
     'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    data: { 'YTParam' : 'test' }
})
```

You can set `contentType` directly as a property, but I'm not 100% sure of this.

Comment: I do this, it returned blank.

Comment: when I echo 's', it did returned 's' in my console, may I know why $_POST['YTParam'] have nothing?

Comment: @EltonJamie Edited to answer your second problem. And answered your related other question too!

Answer (score 2):

The PHP spits out the entire HTML and that's what gets sent to your browser. To correct that, you have to do your parsing before the HTML code and call exit(), so that no HTML gets sent to the browser. Take this code out of the HTML body:

```
<?php

echo $_POST["YTParam"];

if($_POST["YTParam"])
 {
    $YTParam = $_POST["YTParam"];
    echo $YTParam;
}

?>
```

And replace it with this. Placing it at the top of your script, before the opening  tag:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["YTParam"]))
{
     $YTParam = $_POST["YTParam"];
     echo $YTParam;
     exit;
}

?>
```